# dll not found exception Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser.dll on Windows 2012, for Sql Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, dllnotfoundexception

I am working on Front-end VS2010 C# 4.0, Back-end MS Sql Server 2012.
OS - Windows Server 2012.

I am getting this error Message.
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Cause of this error is because of the OS is 64 bit and the BatchParser.dll is of 32 bit.
i have find solution for sql server 2005 & 2008, but when i am going to install the upgrade, it gives message 'a higher version is installed.'. If the provided fix is not for Sql 2012, then please suggest the solution of this problem on Sql Server 2012.